# Separate outlying residuals from dataset R

Tags: r, outliers

I've created a linear model for my dataset which consists of ~12M rows. Using the residuals I established boundaries for outliers. Lower fence and upper fence.

Now I want to extract the outliers and put their corresponding data in a vector or a write them to a file.

Here's two rows from my original dataset:

```
 print(res[1:2,])
 PIG_ID trial       res$bla   gain        LINE      CODE     comp BIRTH_WEIGHT_SCALED farm_trend birth_weight_scaled
 123456   XXX  0012345ABCDFF  1000        CCDDC        Z     <NA>               955.2         -9                  -9
 135411   XXX  11122233ASDDD  889         TTDDT        Z     <NA>                 0.0         -9                  -9
```

resid(lmfit) outputs a bunch of values:

```
 700       750      2132      3394      4123      4213      4583      4842      5288      8287     12331     12427     13726
```

Here is the code that calculates the model and outliers:

```
lmfit = lm(res$gain ~ res$trial + res$bla * res$LINE* res$CODE + res$birth_weight_scaled )

kwant <- quantile(resid(lmfit), probs= c(0.25, 0.75))
Q1 <- kwant[1]
Q3 <- kwant[2]
sigma <- IQR(resid(lmfit))
upp_multi <- 3.5        ##Amount of times sigma for outlier calculation
low_multi <- 1.5        ##Amount of times sigma for outlier calculation

upp_fence <- Q3+(upp_multi * sigma)
low_fence <- Q1-(low_multi * sigma)

print(paste("Upper fence: ", upp_fence, " \t  Lower Fence: ", low_fence ,"\n"))
```

I've been googling and trying pieces of code without success.

Pseudo code would be as following:

```
if(resid(lmfit)>upp_fence){add res[row] to vector OutlierUpperBoundary }
if(resid(lmfit)<low_fence){add res[row] to vector OutlierLowerBoundary }
```

Is there a way to separate the outlying residuals with the rows from my original dataset("Res") and put them in a matrix?

Expected output would be a matrix containing the rows with outliers:

```
 PIG_ID trial       res$bla   gain        LINE      CODE     comp BIRTH_WEIGHT_SCALED farm_trend birth_weight_scaled
 135411   XXX  11122233ASDDD  889         TTDDT        Z     <NA>                 0.0         -9                  -9
```

***Edit***

Using the following for loop copies the whole size of the original matrix but just adds values to the outlying rows:

```
OutliersUpperBoundary <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(res)))
for (row in 1:length(resid(lmfit))){
    if(resid(lmfit)[row]>upp_fence){
        OutliersUpperBoundary[row,] <- res[row,]
    }
}
```

Result:

```
694          NA <NA>           <NA>   NA  <NA> <NA>       <NA>     NA NA  NA
695          NA <NA>           <NA>   NA  <NA> <NA>       <NA>     NA NA  NA
696   112341234  XXX 11213421LAAAAA  915 TTTTT    B       <NA>  175.2 -9  -9
697          NA <NA>           <NA>   NA  <NA> <NA>       <NA>     NA NA  NA
698          NA <NA>           <NA>   NA  <NA> <NA>       <NA>     NA NA  NA
```

In what way should I change my for loop to only grab the rows with values? (I think rbind might work here)

Also, knowing a little bit of R, I think there must be a faster way then using a for loop (My dataset is 12M+ rows and I have to go trough this process 14 times.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a loop.

```
OutlierUpperBoundary <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(res)))

out_index <- 1
for(row in 1:length(resid(lmfit))){
    if(resid(lmfit)[row]>upp_fence){
        OutlierUpperBoundary[out_index, ] <- res[row, ]
        out_index <- out_index + 1
    }
}
```

That *may* take a long time if your `res` table is large. In that case, pre-allocating the full matrix will be faster. Then you can simply remove the NA rows at the end.

```
OutlierUpperBoundary <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(res), nrow = nrow(res)))

out_index <- 1
for(row in 1:length(resid(lmfit))){
    if(resid(lmfit)[row]>upp_fence){
        OutlierUpperBoundary[out_index, ] <- res[row, ]
        out_index <- out_index + 1
    }
}

OutlierUpperBoundary <- OutlierUpperBoundary[complete.cases(OutlierUpperBoundary), ]
```

And you can add the residual value to the output by combining it with the original row in with `cbind()` when you do the assignment.

```
OutlierUpperBoundary <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(res) + 1, nrow = nrow(res)))

out_index <- 1
for(row in 1:length(resid(lmfit))){
    if(resid(lmfit)[row]>upp_fence){
        OutliersUpperBoundary[out_index,] <- cbind(res[row,], resid(lmfit)[row])

        out_index <- out_index + 1
    }
}

OutlierUpperBoundary <- OutlierUpperBoundary[complete.cases(OutlierUpperBoundary), ]
```

Comment: This actually copies the complete matrix, and only puts values in the outlying rows. The rest is marked as <NA>. I'll edit my original question with more info :)

Comment: Oops! That can be fixed by incrementing the output index separately. Edited.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick! On a side note: I edited the = signs in your posts to <-, as this is correct syntax in R.

Comment: Also, knowing a little bit of R, I think there must be a faster way then using a for loop (My dataset is 12M+ rows and I have to go trough this process 14 times.)

Comment: You're right there probably is a better way. I added a solution that will be faster on a larger dataset. Hopefully that helps for now.

Comment: Thanks alot! just one more question I hope you'll be able to answer, how would I go about adding the value of the residual into an extra column, so I can check the values of the outliers in my plot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Added how to add the residual value to the output too. Not sure if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I changed list() to cbind() in order to add the extra column!